# Install problems 'pecl install ibm_db2', how to resolve following issue? MacOSX

Tags: php, db2, ibm-midrange, pecl

I am attempting to install **ibm_db2** via **pecl**. I am having no luck. Below is a sample of the console output im getting. Am I missing a compiler library? It looks as if I am.

...

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/include/php/Zend/zend_API.h:593:36: note: expanded from macro 'ZVAL_STRINGL'
                ZVAL_NEW_STR(z, zend_string_init(s, l, 0));             \
                                                 ^
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/include/php/Zend/zend_types.h:705:23: note: expanded from macro 'ZVAL_NEW_STR'
                zend_string *__s = (s);                                 \
                                    ^
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/include/php/Zend/zend_string.h:168:69: note: passing argument to parameter 'str' here
static zend_always_inline zend_string *zend_string_init(const char *str, size_t len, int persistent)
                                                                    ^
/Users/mcroteau/Downloads/tmp/pear/ibm_db2/ibm_db2.c:7688:77: warning: passing 'SQLUINTEGER *' (aka 'unsigned int *') to parameter of type 'SQLINTEGER *' (aka 'int *') converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
        rc = SQLBindCol(hstmt, 1, SQL_C_CHAR, last_id, MAX_IDENTITY_DIGITS, &out_length);
                                                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/dsdriver/include/sqlcli.h:669:60: note: passing argument to parameter 'pcbValue' here
                                        SQLLEN      FAR   *pcbValue);
                                                           ^
/Users/mcroteau/Downloads/tmp/pear/ibm_db2/ibm_db2.c:7702:20: warning: result of comparison against a string literal is unspecified (use strncmp instead) [-Wstring-compare]
        if(last_id != "") {
                   ^  ~~
/Users/mcroteau/Downloads/tmp/pear/ibm_db2/ibm_db2.c:7820:77: error: use of undeclared identifier 'IS_TYPE_IMMUTABLE'
    if (params && Z_TYPE_P(params) == IS_ARRAY && (Z_TYPE_FLAGS_P(params) & IS_TYPE_IMMUTABLE)) {
                                                                            ^
62 warnings and 2 errors generated.
make: *** [ibm_db2.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed`
```

Comment: Do you have the db2 client installed?

Comment: Check if there's a conflict of PHP versions between the PHP version installed by default on OSX versus the PHP version in MAMP.  When multiple versions of PHP are installed then great care is required when building extensions, and sometimes special build instructions are necessary. Prove by running the `pecl install ibm_db2` command on an OSX image that does not have MAMP, but has the correct kind of Db2-client installed along with the documented prereqs.

Comment: No, I have "IBM Data Server Driver Package 11.1.3.3" installed. Do I need the client instead? @jmarkmurphy

https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24044640

Comment: I believe that IBM_db2 requires the database client. Or, if you are trying to connect to IBM i as the [ibm-midrange] tag indicates you will need DB2 Connect which provides DRDA capability that the DB2 client does not. BTW: DB2 Connect is $$$$$$$. You may want to try ODBC instead. That driver comes with iACS.

Comment: This is one of the places where DB2 for LUW differs from DB2 for i (and z/OS for that matter). You need DB2 Connect to get the DRDA features. I have always used ODBC when accessing DB2 for i from Windows or Linux with PHP. Just because of the cost factor.

Comment: Keep @mao 's comment in mind also.